# General Ito Formula for Semimartingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Below I upload a screenshot of the general Ito formula for $d$ dimensional semimartingales, where the superscript $c$ denotes the continuous part of the $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ process. The formula is from the book of Protter (Theorem 33, pg. 81). I have seen also for instance, the same formula [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/25/the-generalized-ito-formula/) (equation 6):

[image]

I would like to know however what is the corresponding expression for a function $f$ of time and $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$, i.e. for $f(X_t,t)-f(X_0,0)$. Can someone write it down and hopefully recommend some references for it? Assume as usual that $f$ is $C^1$ on $t$ and $C^2$ on $x$. Thanks!

Comment: You can look at $(X_t,t)$ as being a semimartingale with values in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ . Protter's version of the formula is general enough to handle that. For the $t$ coordinate most complicated terms should drop out.

Comment: Thank you @KurtG. I have done it that way!

Comment: Actually, the only extra term is $\int_0^t \partial_t f(s,X_s)ds$.